# Google Charts Dashboard, AJAX call fails to load data from SQL DB

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Ive been trying to load data from a SQL table thats generated daily via a SP, Table consists of 4 columns.

My Ajax call gets the data and puts into an array -

[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA47i.png)

Heres my code im using to draw the view and pass the array -

```
var chartData;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Reporting/LeaveList",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            console.log(typeof data);
            chartData = data;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
        }
    }).done(function () {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(createTable);

    });
});

function createTable() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'AnnualLeave');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sick');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
    data.addRow(chartData[0])


    // Create a dashboard.
    var dash_container = document.getElementById('dashboard_div'),
      myDashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dash_container);

    // Create a date range slider
    var myDateSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control_div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Date'
        }
    });

    // Table visualization
    var myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table_div'
    });

    // Bind myTable to the dashboard, and to the controls
    // this will make sure our table is update when our date changes
    myDashboard.bind(myDateSlider, myTable);

    // Line chart visualization
    var myLine = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'containerId': 'line_div',
    });

    // Bind myLine to the dashboard, and to the controls

    myDashboard.bind(myDateSlider, myLine);

    myDashboard.draw(data);
```

And heres some of the controller -

```
data = (
                from u in db.StaffReportingDay
                select new StaffReportingDayVM
                {
                    Date = u.Date.ToString(),
                    AnnualLeave = u.AnnualLeave,
                    CompassionateLeave = u.CompassionateLeave,
                    Sick = u.Sick,
                    StudyLeave = u.StudyLeave,
                    Total = u.Total
                }).ToList();
                }


        var ChartOne = new object[data.Count + 1];
        ChartOne[0] = new object[]
        {
            "Date",
            "Annual Leave",
            "Sick Leave",
            "Total on Leave"
        };

        int j = 0;

        foreach(var i in data)
        {
            j++;
            ChartOne[j] = new object[] {i.Date.ToString(), i.AnnualLeave, i.Sick, i.Total };
        }


        return Json(ChartOne, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

What i cant get is the array to pull into the view, i just get an error -

**Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value Annual Leave does not match type number in column index 1**

Ive tried many things but would like some pointers and other people to give their insight please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
 function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'AnnualLeave');
    data.addColumn('number', 'CompassionateLeave');
    data.addColumn('number', 'StudyLeave');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sick');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
    $.each(chartData, function (i, row) {
        data.addRow([
          (new Date(row.Date)),
          parseFloat(row.AnnualLeave),
          parseFloat(row.CompassionateLeave),
          parseFloat(row.StudyLeave),
          parseFloat(row.Sick),
          parseFloat(row.Total)
        ]);
    });
```